# Firing a laser through a pile of cubes

Tags: mathematics

Find the number of integer triples $(a,b,c)$ such that there exists $0<t<1$ with

$| a + \frac{1}{2} - 589t| < \frac{1}{2}$

$| b + \frac{1}{2} - 989t| < \frac{1}{2} $

$| c + \frac{1}{2} - 1189t| < \frac{1}{2}$

Comment: I actually think this is on-topic.  At first it appears as a textbook-style puzzle but the title hints that it isn't.  In fact, the solution due to  f'' shows it isn't a textbook style problem at all and instead has a very clever solution.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As the title suggests, the question has this more accessible interpretation:

> Divide 3-space into unit cubes such that their vertices are lattice points. How many cubes contain part of the line segment with endpoints $(0,0,0)$ and $(589,989,1189)$?

The line segment crosses $588$ integer $x$-coordinates, $988$ $y$-coordinates, and $1188$ $z$-coordinates, entering a new cube each time. Because $589$, $989$, and $1189$ are pairwise relatively prime, it never crosses two integer coordinates at the same time. The total number of cubes it passes through is therefore $588+988+1188+1=2765$.